# shared buffer processes

Tags: c

I am trying to call functions that are add some characters to the buffer and then remove them after. but am still failing to call the function properly.  I am working on Linux.

```
ERROR: q_add makes an integer without a cast.
```

This is part of the code:

```
do {
    printf("Enter shared buffer operation ");
    printf("i(init)/a(add)/r(remove)/t(items)/d(delete)");
    scanf("%c%c", &op, &discard);
    int a=1;
    char n;

    switch ( op )
    {
      case 'i':
               printf("Enter nnumber a leter here!");
               scanf("%c" &n)
               q_add(a, &n);
               break;

      case 'a':
               q_delete();
               break;

      case 'r':
               q_remove(a, &n);
               break;
       //------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The definition of `q_add()` in the appropriate file is:

```
 void q_add(int n, char *x)
 {
    shbuf->count += n;
    while ( n-- > 0 )
    {
        shbuf->buf[shbuf->inspos++] = *x++;
        if ( shbuf->inspos ==  QSIZ )
            shbuf->inspos = 0;
    }
 }
```

And this function doesn't really work; if I uncomment the exit, I get an error:

```
 void q_delete()
 {
    if ( -1 == shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0) )
    {
        perror("Can't remove shared mem");
        //exit(1);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the function as:

```
int a; 
char n;
....
q_add(a, n);
```

but the def is:

```
void q_add(int n, char *x)
```

It expects a `char *` as the 2nd argument and you are sending a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

`q_add(1, &n);`?

Comment: I tried this, and it returned a segmentation error, after executing and entering the value

Comment: You never set a to anything valid.  That's probably why it's segfaulting.

Comment: Looking at your code, use `q_add(1, &n);` because you only have one char

Comment: tried that! however after entering the character, it doesnt switch to the next function.just keeps bring "printf("i(init)/a(add)/r(remove)/t(items)/d(delete)"); 
"